# Import statements in modules in Python

Tags: python, module, python-import

Let's say I have a module that defines a function:

```
# import time
def printTime():
    import time
    print 'the time is ' + time.time()
```

I my main app, I load the function like this:

```
from modules.Help import printTime
if somecondition:
    # from modules.Help import printTime
    printTime()
```

In modules, should I do all imports at the top of the file?
Or, since the module is only required under certain conditions, should I do the import in the function?
What is more economical, or is there no difference?

In PHP, there is the require_once. Are the import statements at the top of submodules optimised in the same way?
I have some duplicate imports (e.g. time) in both the parent and submodule. Should I worry about the number of packages that I import in submodules?

Comment: Once you make an import, every new import shouldn't cost you more, Just for the sake of keeping things in respective scope, I'd do each import only when necessary.

Comment: I'd argue that this is somewhat subjective, and varies by programmer preference, and what style guide you're working off - you're unlikely to notice any performance hit. My personal preference (based on the Google style guide) is to unconditionally import any module that's used, always at the top of the file.